# Binding which is secure, interoprable (.NET and Java clients), over internet, and easy to implement

Tags: java, .net, wcf, soa

At my workplace we are trying to implement a WCF service. Our requirements are:

- Interoprable with different platforms (Java, .NET, Android , iOS)
- Topmost security (financial institution)
- Over the internet

Which is the most suitable binding for the above requirements?

Comment: One of the HTTP bindings, using SSL - WebAPI might be a good place to start looking.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and considered so far, and what the specific issues/problems/concerns with those solutions were.

Comment: we tried wshttp with message security and username password..but java client were not able to create proxies ....we used axis project on the java side to consume services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with [WCF express interop bindings](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Express%20Interop%20Bindings)